# Как начать изучать rSocket?

Tags: java, websocket, tcp, reactive

Я пытаюсь начать изучать rSocket, но не могу найти хороших источников информации.

Документации для JS практически нет и она устарела

Можете ли вы поделиться какими-либо ресурсами, чтобы освоить эту технологию практически с нулевыми знаниями о ней? Я уже знаю о WebSocket и TCP и создавал проекты с их использованием.

Мне нужны хорошие источники информации о rSocket или пошаговые примеры кода.

Спасибо!

Comment: посмотрите на официальном сайте https://rsocket.io/ , там есть примеры всего что нужно